# How to replace lines which has no data with the previous line's data

Tags: text-processing, scripting

Input

```
Time      Value  Flag
06:15:10  49.95  Actual
00:00:00  0.00  NoValue
06:22:50  49.94  Actual
06:23:00  49.93  Actual
06:23:10  49.93  Actual
06:23:20  49.93  Actual
06:23:30  49.93  Actual
06:24:40  49.92  Actual
00:00:00  0.00  NoValue
```

I have to replace the lines contains "NoValue".
Time will be replaced with last recorded time with the increment of 10s (10seconds)
Value will be replaced with last recorded time
Flag will be replaced with Actual

My result will be displayed as,

```
Time      Value  Flag
06:15:10  49.95  Actual
06:15:20  49.95  Actual
06:22:50  49.94  Actual
06:23:00  49.93  Actual
06:23:10  49.93  Actual
06:23:20  49.93  Actual
06:23:30  49.93  Actual
06:24:40  49.92  Actual
06:24:50  49.92  Actual
```

Comment: Please read https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/formatting and look at other questions that have been upvoted and answered (or even look at your own previous questions which others have fixed for you) to see how to format input, output, and code blocks and then [edit] your question to fix it. Also add what you've tried to solve the problem yourself.

Comment: Yes. I have modified the formatting of my question.

Comment: I have tried awk, means blank lines will be filled with the previous line's data. But in this case, I am unable to replace and change the data with that logic

Comment: awk 'NF {p = $0} {print p}' file tried this in case of blank lines.

Comment: As I mentioned, [edit] your question to fix it. Don't add code or requirements or any other information in comments where it can't be formatted and could be missed.

Comment: what would happen if there were two lines repeated with "NoValue"? same timestamp will be replaced? or second NoValue line will  be added another +10 seconds? what will happen if all data were NoValue? or second line start with NoValue line?

Comment: My requirement is, in the infile if there is any any line containing NoValue, it would be replaced with the previous line data but the time will be increased by 10secs

Comment: [you didn't answer none of my questions I asked](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/680502/how-to-replace-lines-which-has-no-data-with-the-previous-lines-data/680518#comment1285878_680502).

Comment: If my two lines repeated with "NoValue", then those two lines will be replaced with the +10s timestamp and but with the last value. 0.00 will be replaced with the last good value but time will be increased by +10s

Comment: Again (3rd/last time) - [edit] your question to fix it. Don't add code or requirements or any other information in comments where it can't be formatted and could be missed.

Comment: This looks like it falls a little outside the scope of U&L as it's more a programming question.  There's limits to what it's worth trying to achieve on the command line... I'd suggest taking some time to [learn some python](https://www.learnpython.org/).  It's available on most systems.

Comment: I rolled back because you opened a new question https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/681360/72456 for it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
awk -F'[: ]+' -v addSec=10 '
 NR>1 && /Actual/{
     sec=(($1*3600)+($2*60)+$3) +addSec;
     prevTime=sprintf("%02d:%02d:%02d", sec/3600, sec%3600/60, sec%60) OFS $4 OFS $5;
 }
 /NoValue/{ $0=prevTime }1
' infile
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But it didn't work in my case.

Comment: @Nainita it absolutely works based on what you provided as an input and expected output in your question. It won't work if you have something else other than what you shown in your question definitely that's why several times we asked you to update your question. I will be informed and possibly update my question whenever you edited your question and clarified enough as well as telling me how it doesn't work.

Comment: Okay. I just copied the same to my system and error generated "system error near line 1". Though I didn't find any syntax error in your code. If you can explain each lines of your code that how it will generate the desired output then it would be really helpful for me. I will try finding why this error is generating in my system.

Comment: @Nainita it would be nice to show how do you run the code in somewhere in body of your question. just copy your given example into a file and name it `infile` then copy the whole code above and run. if doesn't work add the code +error into your question so that I can see  how it doesn't work. additionally you might want to add your `awk --version` too, thanks

Comment: I have modified my question. I can exclude the time incremental part, only the lines match with the pattern "NoValue" will be replaced by previous line. Can you just simplify the code. Somehow the code is not working in my system. My system OS is Solaris 5.8.

Comment: @Nainita replace `awk` with `nawk` or `/usr/xpg4/bin/awk` and try again. for revised question, it is strongly recommended to rollback your edit since you invalidated all the answers you received.

Comment: with adding +10s, you would just need `nawk 'NR>1 && /Actual/{
     prev=$0;
 }
 /NoValue/{ $0=prev }1' infile`.

Comment: Don't use nawk, it's older and further from POSIX compliant (i.e. has fewer features) than /usr/xpg4/bin/awk.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

cat noval | tr -s " " | awk -F"[: ]" -f val.awk

where:

```
cat noval 
06:15:10  49.95  Actual
00:00:00  0.00  
06:22:50  49.94  Actual
06:23:00  49.93  Actual
06:23:10  49.93  Actual
06:23:20  49.93  Actual
06:23:30  49.93  Actual
06:24:40  49.92  Actual
00:00:00  0.00
```

and

```
cat val.awk
{
    if($5=="") {
        print g
                   }
        else {
               print $0
           $3=$3+10
               if ($3>59){
        $3=$3-60
        $2=$2+1
               }
               if ($2>59){
                  $2=$2-60
                  $1=$1+1
               }
if(length($1)<2) {$1="0"$1}
if(length($2)<2) {$2="0"$2}
if(length($3)<2) {$3="0"$3}
               g=$1":"$2":"$3" "$4" "$5
              }
}
```

and the result is:

```
06:15:10 49.95 Actual
06:15:20 49.95 Actual
06:22:50 49.94 Actual
06:23:00 49.93 Actual
06:23:10 49.93 Actual
06:23:20 49.93 Actual
06:23:30 49.93 Actual
06:24:40 49.92 Actual
06:24:50 49.92 Actual
```

Notes: using awk we are breaking down each line along the characters colon (:) and also space. This is so that we can access the three components for time stamp (columns 1,2,3) for possible addition of 10. We use tr to compress multiple spaces to just one. The F flag in awk is set to breakdown the lines along colon and/or space for action.

Comment: Could you please explain the "if" part?

Comment: It simply checks to see if the last column has no value. I have used NoValue as in your question; but if that column is actually blank then you need to change it to if($5=="").

Comment: You are quite right. I have edited the code to print the correct timestamp

Answer (score -1):

You can't determine a new time by adding 10 seconds to an existing time without knowing the date and timezone that the timestamps apply to and using utilities that understand dates and times (i.e. not just simple math) since the new time that's the result of adding 10 seconds to a given time is affected by Daylight Savings Time and Leap Seconds.

Assuming that the start date for your input timestamps is today then using GNU awk for time functions (which handle DST but, as is common with all tools that handle POSIX epoch time, do not handle leap seconds so hopefully you don't care about that):

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN {
    OFS = "  "
    prevDate = (date=="" ? strftime("%Y %m %d") : date)
}
NR == 1 {
    print
    next
}
$3 == "NoValue" {
    prevTime = gensub(/:/," ","g",prevLine[1])
    prevSecs = mktime(prevDate " " prevTime)
    currSecs = prevSecs + 10
    prevDate = strftime("%Y %m %d",currSecs)
    $1 = strftime("%T",currSecs)
    $2 = prevLine[2]
    $3 = prevLine[3]
}
{
    print
    split($0,prevLine)
}
```

```
$ awk -f tst.awk file
Time      Value  Flag
06:15:10  49.95  Actual
06:15:20  49.95  Actual
06:22:50  49.94  Actual
06:23:00  49.93  Actual
06:23:10  49.93  Actual
06:23:20  49.93  Actual
06:23:30  49.93  Actual
06:24:40  49.92  Actual
06:24:50  49.92  Actual
```

If you want the time calculations to be applied in some other timezone than the one your computer is set to, then set the shell variable `TZ` appropriately before executing the above or set the UTC flag on the calls to `mktime()` and `strftime()`, see https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Time-Functions.

If you want to use a different start date than today then call the script as `awk -v date='2021 10 03' -f tst.awk file` providing whatever date you like in `YYYY MM DD` format.

The above assumes the timestamp will always be populated in the 2nd line of your input since you didn't say anything about how to handle it otherwise.

Note that as @PhilipCouling pointed out in comments `mktime()` (or any other library) given just a date and time can't robustly return a seconds since the epoch for a timezone that has DST during the transition interval when DST ends (it's fine when DST starts). The example they provided is:

> In the UK the date/time 30-Oct-2022 01:30:00am will happen twice.
> That's because when the clocks get to 2am, DST will end and the clocks
> jump back an hour to 1am. So 1:30 happens once before DST ends and
> once after DST ends. The file does not contain any information about
> which of these two it's describing. The file does not tell you if DST
> has ended or not.

Comment: The first paragraph is misleading. DST is only a problem if you are specifically working in geographic time zone such as those in the IANA database. A time zone like BST or EDT or just UTC have no daylight savings concept. Leap seconds are very rarely implemented by libraries and nearly always irrelevant. They are usually implemented by smearing over 24 hours and contexts where they may be a problem don't usually use UTC but something like [International Atomic Time](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Atomic_Time) which doesn't have them.

Comment: @PhilipCouling not sure why you think that first paragraph is misleading, many of us work in time zones that have DST. Yes, I said that leap seconds aren't handled by tools that work with POSIX epoch time. I mentioned UTC in the context of gawk as it has a UTC flag as one way to avoid DST issues.

Comment: I have modified my question. I can exclude the time incremental part, only the lines match with the pattern "NoValue" will be replaced by previous line. Can you just simplify the code. Somehow the code is not working in my system. My system OS is Solaris 5.8.

Comment: The time increment is the only interesting part about your current question. Don't make such significant changes to your question after you've received answers to it. Accept an answer to the question you asked and then ask a new question if you got your question wrong first time you asked it.

Comment: Sorry to be a pain but your answer is wrong. Now I think about it there are 3 problems: 1) the code can't tell if the clocks jumped back yet or not.  So without the file stating a UTC offset it's an impossible problem. 2) the opening blanket phrase is much too strong. You **can** just add 10 seconds just as long as you are not working in a geographic time zone with DST or not working with time stamps that cross the hour in a single file. 3) the discussion of leap seconds is just muddying the water. It almost never a practical consideration due to the way they are otherwise acounted for.

Comment: I can't imagine why you're saying the answer is wrong. You say `the code can't tell if the clocks jumped back yet or not` but of course it can and does, that's the point of using time functions. You say `you can... long as you are not working in a geographic time zone with DST` - right, so as long as you account for TZ/DST as I said `You can't ...without knowing the date and timezone`. The code uses the current TZ and I state how to change that or set the UTC flag if you don't want to use your current TZ. It's always worth mentioning any caveat to an answer, leap seconds included.

Comment: @PhilipCouling my answer states the issues around trying to just use math, provides a clear, robust solution using an extremely common Unix tool, GNU awk, states how to adjust it's behavior if necessary for other TZs, and states the caveat that it doesn't handle leap seconds. I really can't imagine what more you're looking for from an answer but, whatever it is, I doubt if there's any point us discussing it further.

Comment: @EdMorton Final comment, there is a bug in your code. In the UK the date/time `30-Oct-2022 01:30:00am` will happen **twice**. That's because when the clocks get to 2am, DST will end and the clocks jump back an hour to 1am.  So `1:30` happens once before DST ends and once after DST ends.  The file does not contain any information about which of these two it's describing.  The file does not tell you if DST has ended or not.  It really doesn't matter what standard library you use, you're trying to solve an impossible problem!

Comment: Finally, a constructive comment! NOW I understand what you were trying to say when you said `the code can't tell if the clocks jumped back yet or not`. So the problem is that `mktime()` can't robustly return a `seconds since the epoch` for a timezone that has DST during the transition interval. Interesting - thank you for pointing that out and providing that example.