# Replace the whole line with the previous line's data (whatever it is) if pattern matches

Tags: text-processing

InputFile

```
Time      Value  Flag
06:15:10  49.95  Actual
00:00:00  0.00  NoValue
06:22:50  49.94  Actual
06:23:00  49.93  Actual
06:23:10  49.93  Actual
06:23:20  49.93  Actual
06:23:30  49.93  Actual
06:24:40  49.92  Actual
00:00:00  0.00  NoValue
```

I have to replace the whole line that matches with the word `NoValue`. Which means whenever the script will find a line with `NoValue`, it will replace the whole line with last recorded time.

My result will be displayed as,

```
Time      Value  Flag
06:15:10  49.95  Actual
06:15:10  49.95  Actual
06:22:50  49.94  Actual
06:23:00  49.93  Actual
06:23:10  49.93  Actual
06:23:20  49.93  Actual
06:23:30  49.93  Actual
06:24:40  49.92  Actual
06:24:40  49.92  Actual
```

I have tried

```
awk 'NR%3==NoValue{ name=$0; next } { print name, $0 }' Inputfile
```

But it is merging the lines which I dont want.

My OS version is Solaris 5.8

Comment: `NR%3` is a number, 0, 1, or 2. `$3` is the third field. `print name, $0` means "print the contents of the variable `name` then also print the current line next to that, separated by `OFS`"

Comment: Yes. I want awk will read each lines and replace the lines contains the match "NoValue" with the previous line's data.

Comment: I am not an expert in awk and sed but these two are very useful in case of text processing. I have used sed to replace a single word but unable to replace the whole line in one shot

Comment: Why post a dupe to a question you've already posted a bounty on?  [How to replace lines which has no data with the previous line's data](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/680502/how-to-replace-lines-which-has-no-data-with-the-previous-lines-data)

Comment: @cas it's not duplicate, there asked for +10seconds incremental, here it is only copy it. I rolled back the previous one to its original asked revision which was making this new post duplicates of it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the stream editor sed, we can do as shown:

```
sed -e '
  h
  $!N
  /Actual\n.*NoValue$/ {
    g
    G
  }
  P
  D
' Input file
```

---

- Assuming you are on a bourne shell or its variant, running on the command line.
- The sed code is examining two lines at a time, and if the first line ends in "Actual" and second ends in "NoValue", in that scenario erase the second line and in its place fill in the first.
- Now print the first line(P), remove it(D) and with the existing pattern space re run  the sed code on it, provided it is non empty.

Comment: Yes, works absolutely fine. Thanks a lot @guest_7.

Comment: You don't need to examine two lines at a time, if you always store the previous line into hold space - see [my answer](/a/683306/112566).

Comment: @Toby Speight thanks for suggesting a much superior solution!

Answer (score 6):

With `awk` you can print the previous line if the condition `$3 == "NoValue"` is true:

```
awk '$3 == "NoValue" { $0=prev }{prev=$0} 1' file
Time      Value  Flag
06:15:10  49.95  Actual
06:15:10  49.95  Actual
06:22:50  49.94  Actual
06:23:00  49.93  Actual
06:23:10  49.93  Actual
06:23:20  49.93  Actual
06:23:30  49.93  Actual
06:24:40  49.92  Actual
06:24:40  49.92  Actual
```

You can see: "Print previous line if condition is met": https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27740937/print-previous-line-if-condition-is-met

Answer (score 0):

This is easy to do with just two lines of sed.  All we need to do is copy each line into hold space before we print it.  We can then use that saved copy of the previous line to replace any that ends with `NoValue`:

```bsh
#!/bin/sed -f

# for "NoValue" lines, replace with line from hold space
/NoValue$/g

# Store to hold space before printing
h
```

This script is short enough to pass in `-e` arguments:

```bsh
sed -e '/NoValue$/g' -e h
```

Result:

```
Time      Value  Flag
06:15:10  49.95  Actual
06:15:10  49.95  Actual
06:22:50  49.94  Actual
06:23:00  49.93  Actual
06:23:10  49.93  Actual
06:23:20  49.93  Actual
06:23:30  49.93  Actual
06:24:40  49.92  Actual
06:24:40  49.92  Actual
```

This will replace consecutive `NoValue` lines with the last preceding `Actual` line - that seems a reasonable interpretation of the requirement, though the question is silent on that matter.